# Which is the analytic expression of the function in the picture?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

I am trying to write down the analytic expression of the function drawn in this picture:

[image]

The things I noticed are: it behaves like $-1/|x|$ in the origin and like $1/|x|$ at infinity. Also, it changes is concavity in the highest point. Nonetheless, I don not know how to write its analytic expression.

Could someone please tell what it could be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the function is not specified in a precise way, there's obviously not "the analytic expression of the function". Could you elaborate what kind of functions are you looking for? Rational functions? Can involve trigonometric functions?

Comment: @jjagmath actually I expect something like $\pm 1/|x|$ (but just looking at its behaviour in the origin). I guess it is not important e.g. for the exercise which is exactly that maximum which appears. Maybe we can assume it is $f(-3)= 5$ and then try to write the analytic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Look for something of the form $- \frac{ax+b}{x^2}$ for some positive numbers $a$ and $b$.

Look [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wallfbsbcs)

Comment: jjagmath, thank you. I know I’ve already accepted your answer but may I ask you anyway your help in finding an example with no rational functions? Thank you in advance.